# Associated primes and Cohen-Macaulay rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, cohen-macaulay

In the book *Cohen-Macaulay rings by Bruns and Herzog*. Part of theorem 2.1.2 states

> Let $(R,m)$ be a Noetherian local ring, and $M\neq0$ a Cohen-Macaulay $R$-module. Then $\dim R/p=\operatorname{depth}M$ for all $p\in\operatorname{Ass}M$.

If $M=R$ and if $R/p$ is Cohen-Macaulay, then we would have $\operatorname{depth}R/p=\operatorname{depth}R$.

So, does there exist such C-M ring $(R,m)$ with some $p\in \operatorname{Ass}R$ so that $R/p$ is not Cohen-Macaulay? (I am especially curious about the case where $R$ is a Cohen-Macaulay affine ring (i.e. $R=k[x_1,...,x_n]/I$ for some ideal $I\in k[x_1,...,x_n]$ where $k$ is a field) if we don't assume $R$ to be local.)

Comment: So, you are looking for a C-M ring $R$ and an associated prime $p$ of $R$ such that $R/p$ is not C-M? (This does not have much sense for domains.)

Comment: I posted this on MO. See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/419314)